# update sql table using ironpython

Tags: python, sap, ironpython

I'm writting script in ironpython on  SAP CPQ in which I need to update a custom table. AddRow() function is just inserting the row in the table. Would someone tell me any function which updates the table row

```
tablerow = { "CpqTableEntryId" : currentQuoteCpqTableEntryId, "OpportunityId" : oppId, "QuoteNumber" : Quote.CompositeNumber, "IsPrimary" : 1 }
tableInfo.AddRow(tablerow)
SqlHelper.Upsert(tableInfo)
```

Comment: Would someone help me here?

Comment: This is something they say on documentation


#insert
tableInfo = SqlHelper.GetTable("ITEMMASTERFROMNS")
tablerow = { "item_internal_id" : itemInternalId, "item_sku" : sku }
tableInfo.AddRow(tablerow)
upsertResult = SqlHelper.Upsert(tableInfo)




#update
tablerow = { "CpqTableEntryId" : currentQuoteCpqTableEntryId, "OpportunityId" : oppId, "QuoteNumber" : Quote.CompositeNumber, "IsPrimary" : 1 }
tableInfo.AddRow(tablerow)
SqlHelper.Upsert(tableInfo)

Comment: Would somebody tell me the difference in query mentioned under insert and update

Comment: This is still pending.. Would someone will help me here?